# Azure DevOps pipeline: specific stage gets stuck in queue on a specific machine

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

- Specific stage gets stuck in queue only on a specific machine
- Shows position in queue: 1, but cannot connect to the agent, even though no other jobs are running and the queue is empty
- All other stages work fine
- Fault stage works fine on a different machine
- Agent is online and enabled
- All our agents are self hosted on local machines
- This stage runs SonarQube analysis
- Tried restarting agent, machine, install new one on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Check wether your Azure DevOps agent has the [agent capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities) that may be needed by your stage. A stage may have certain [demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) that need to be satisfied by the agent.

Comment: Checked and everything looks fine. After playing with this stage I found that the problem is caused by SonarQubeAnalyze@4 task, when I delete it stage gets assigned to an agent with no problems and runs just as it should, but obviously doesn't perform analysis. If I add this one line back, agent does not see the whole stage, and it's stuck in queue.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: turns out Java had to be installed not only globally, but also for user account running agent